QTabWidget is tiny compared to container
I am trying to create a gui screen that has a set of tabs and a tool bar but the tab widget is only filling the very top corner of the screen and the toolbar buttons are overlapping it. This is despite the actual window showing in fullscreen.
enter image description here
The code I have using is included below.
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTabWidget, QGridLayout, QToolButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor

from devtunnel import toggleServerActive

# Defines a testing function to visualise widgets as blocks of colour
def applyBlockColour(widget : QWidget, colour : str):
    widget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
    pallette = widget.palette()
    pallette.setColor(widget.backgroundRole(), QColor(colour))
    widget.setPalette(pallette)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.tabs = QTabWidget(self)
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar("main")

# Defines the basic tab class which containes each tab window
class Tab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, colour : str, window : MainWindow, tab_name : str):
        super(Tab, self).__init__()
        applyBlockColour(self, colour)

        self.layout_style = QGridLayout(self)

        window.tabs.addTab(self, tab_name)

    def add_tab_item(self, tab_item) -> None:
        row = tab_item.positioning[0]
        column = tab_item.positioning[1]
        rowSpan = tab_item.positioning[2]
        columnSpan = tab_item.positioning[3]
        self.layout_style.addWidget(tab_item, row, column, rowSpan, columnSpan)


# Defines an item that is located within a tab
class TabItem(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, colour: str, parent : Tab, row : int, column : int, rowSpan = 1, columnSpan = 1):
        super(TabItem, self).__init__()
        applyBlockColour(self, colour)

        self.positioning = [row, column, rowSpan, columnSpan]

        self.layout_style = QGridLayout(self)

        parent.add_tab_item(self)

#Defines a button that is located on a tool bar
class ToolBarButton(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, parent : MainWindow, text : str, func):
        super(ToolBarButton, self).__init__()
        self.setText(text)
        font = self.font()
        font.setBold(True)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.clicked.connect(func)
        parent.toolbar.addWidget(self)

def devtunnelToggle():
    state = toggleServerActive()
    if state:
        pass


# Creates the main window
app = QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()

#Adds buttons to the toolbar
close_button = ToolBarButton(main_window, "X", main_window.window().close)

devtunnel_button = ToolBarButton(main_window, "Disabled", devtunnelToggle)

overview_screen = Tab('red', main_window, "Overview")

teams_screen = Tab('blue', main_window, "Teams")


#Loads the app and shows it in full screen
main_window.showFullScreen()

#Closes the program properly when the gui window is closed
sys.exit(app.exec())```

I was expecting the tool bar to fill the entire window width and then the tab bar to be shown below as wide as the number of tabs.


The self argument you're using in the QTabWidget constructor only makes it a child of the parent (self is the instance of MainWIndow). To ensure that it's properly resized, it must be set as part of a layout manager; QMainWindow has its own layout, and its "central widget" must be set accordingly: in your case, self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs). If you need more widgets in the main layout, then create a QWidget as a "container" central widget, set a layout for it, and add those widgets to that.
